# Displaying wp post from another WP site

Tags: wordpress

I have two WordPress installations, one is main domain and the other one is sub-domain. Also, both sites use different database. Now I want to automatically post content from subdomain to Main Domain.Is there a way to show the most recent post from the second(sub-domain) site on my first(main domain) sites?
Thanks

Comment: If you have an actual WP multisite setup, you can switch the blog id to easily get data from the other “instances.” If it is two completely different systems, then you’re probably best off using the Rest API ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm Able to solve this.
here is the way:
Step 1: Copy the following code wherever you want to display your original WordPress posts:

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed('http://my-subdomain.com/feed/');
if(!empty($rss)):
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(4);
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
endif;
?>
```

Step 2: Add this to your code (preferably right after the snippet above):

```
<ul>
<?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo 'No news.';
else
foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```